# iPhone trying to create a NSDate object, get unexpected @

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to create a NSDate object, and keep getting a error that says "unexpceted @ in program.
The line is
        NSDate *endDate=[ [NSDate alloc] dateWithNaturalLanguageString: @“31/12/01” ];
any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString: @"31/12/01" ]`

`dateWithNaturalLanguageString:` is a class method not an instance method (so don't call alloc).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that method is supported by iOS.  Its available for OSX

Comment: No, it's not available in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of problems here. First, it looks like you copied the code from another source, which added smart quotes to the string. So, instead of `@“31/12/01”` it should be `@"31/12/01"`.

Also, you're using a class method on an instance of `NSDate`. The corrected way to create this date is as follows:

```
NSDate *endDate= [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"31/12/01"];
```